# How to import Google calendar meeting/events information of all users in the organisation from Google Calendar to Google sheets (using API)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

How to import upcoming meeting information of all users in the organisation from Google Calendar to Google sheets (using API).

I have the following code which I tried to use, it works fine but it just gives me ONLY MY calendar events. I'm an admin and I need to pull up all the users calendar events and details for some analysis. Thanks.

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){

//
// Export Google Calendar Events to a Google Spreadsheet
//
// This code retrieves events between 2 dates for the specified calendar.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A2 listing the events,
// dates/times, etc and even calculates event duration (via creating formulas in the spreadsheet) and formats the values.
//
// I do re-write the spreadsheet header in Row 1 with every run, as I found it faster to delete then entire sheet content,
// change my parameters, and re-run my exports versus trying to save the header row manually...so be sure if you change
// any code, you keep the header in agreement for readability!
//
// 1. Please modify the value for mycal to be YOUR calendar email address or one visible on your MY Calendars section of your Google Calendar
// 2. Please modify the values for events to be the date/time range you want and any search parameters to find or omit calendar entires
// Note: Events can be easily filtered out/deleted once exported from the calendar
// 
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event
//

var mycal = "mohammed_zaid@condenast.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

// Optional variations on getEvents
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"));
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"), {search: 'word1'});
// 
// Explanation of how the search section works (as it is NOT quite like most things Google) as part of the getEvents function:
//    {search: 'word1'}              Search for events with word1
//    {search: '-word1'}             Search for events without word1
//    {search: 'word1 word2'}        Search for events with word2 ONLY
//    {search: 'word1-word2'}        Search for events with ????
//    {search: 'word1 -word2'}       Search for events without word2
//    {search: 'word1+word2'}        Search for events with word1 AND word2
//    {search: 'word1+-word2'}       Search for events with word1 AND without word2
//
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("May 23, 2021 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("May 26, 2022 23:59:59 CST"), {search: '-project123'});


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// Uncomment this next line if you want to always clear the spreadsheet content before running - Note people could have added extra columns on the data though that would be lost
// sheet.clearContents();  

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,14);
range.setValues(header);

  
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';
// Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below
// NOTE: I've had problems with the getVisibility for some older events not having a value, so I've had do add in some NULL text to make sure it does not error
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,14);
range.setValues(details);

// Writing formulas from scripts requires that you write the formulas separate from non-formulas
// Write the formula out for this specific row in column 7 to match the position of the field myformula_placeholder from above: foumula over columns F-E for time calc
var cell=sheet.getRange(row,7);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

}
}
function onOpen() {
  Browser.msgBox('App Instructions - Please Read This Message', '1) Click Tools then Script Editor\\n2) Read/update the code with your desired values.\\n3) Then when ready click Run export_gcal_to_gsheet from the script editor.', Browser.Buttons.OK);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the events for each member of the domain, you will simply have to pass the email address of each user as a calendar id. However, since you want to retrieve the events for the members in your domain, it is advisable you use the Calendar API instead.

So for instance, I suggest you make the following changes to your code and make use of the `Calendar` advanced service (which will enable the Calendar API):

```
let optionalArgs = {
   'timeMin': timeMin,
   'timeMax': timeMax,
   ...
   };
let userIds = ['user1id', 'user2id', ...];
for (let i=0; i< userIds.length; i++)
   let events= Calendar.Events.list(userIds[i], optionalArgs);
```

In order to enable the `Calendar` advanced service, you will have to go to **Advanced Services** and search for **Google Calendar API** and add it to the project.

[image: calendar advanced service]

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Events:list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. We have more than 10K users in the system, you mean I should list all of their email ids in the code?

Comment: If you want to retrieve all the events for each user, then you will have to store their ids somewhere in order to be able to access them properly. However, since you mention that you have a large number of users, you might be running into Apps Script's [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). This being said, I would suggest you to make use of the Calendar API and Admin SDK directly and create your own script/application for this (both of these API are subject to quota limits as well).

Comment: I tried a lot but couldn't get the script give what I'm looking for. Anyways, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Why is it not working? Are you receiving any errors? Can you provide more detais?